# как сделать что бы при маленьком разрешении картинка поменялась местами с текстом, но при большом оставалась на прежнем месте

Tags: html, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
    <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading">Death to the Stock Photo:<br>Special   Thanks</h2>
                <p class="lead">A special thanks to <a target="_blank" href="http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/">Death to the Stock Photo</a> for providing the photographs that you see in this template. Visit their website to become a member.</p>


</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ipad.png" alt="">
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте классы `push` и `pull`.
Простой пример: `col-md-push-6` подвинется на 6 вправо, а `col-md-pull-6` - влево. и они поменяются местами

Comment: можно поконкретнее, ато пробую, но не получается у меня, я ставлю col-xs-push-6 блоку с текстом и col-xs-pull-6 блоку с картинкой, но они плывут вообще не понятно куда. Мне надо что бы на мобильниках блок с текстом поменялся местами, а на больших осталось как есть

Answer (score 0):

Продублируйте блок с картинкой вверху и используйте классы  visible-xs и hidden-xs

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6 visible-xs">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ipad.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
    <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <h2 class="section-heading">Death to the Stock Photo:<br>Special   Thanks</h2>
        <p class="lead">A special thanks to <a target="_blank" href="http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/">Death to the Stock Photo</a> for providing the photographs that you see in this template. Visit their website to become a member.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ipad.png" alt="">
</div>
```